# What should be the relationship between the classes of a supermarket management system?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm making a supermarket management system based on c++ and incorporating GUI.

so, when the user enters details and all, there are four categories displayed, namely dairy products, fruits, vegetables, and cooking ingredients. When clicking on any of those, further items from the category show up. For eg, when clicked on dairy products, user can see milk, eggs, and cheese. There's "add to cart" button with all three of them.

Now I'm basically confused about the classes and filing. Firstly, I had thought that dairy products should be a parent + abstract class and have three further child classes namely milk, eggs, cheese. But that would be too many classes and not very efficient I feel. Later, I thought there should be four classes for 4 categories and an instance of class should be created everytime "add to cart" button is clicked. But im still confused on what should be the member variables of the class.. ID (because milk, cheese, eggs must have a different ID), three variables of stock (because stock count for each will be different), and name?

If anyone can help me with the basic classes, their relationships, and the member variables in it.

Thank you!

Here's the code. I'm particularly confused on how to update the stock for a particular item in a file.

```
    #include <string> 
    #include <iostream> 
    using namespace std;
    class Product
    {
       protected: 
       string name; 
       string ID; 
       int count; 
       Product(string n, string id, int c)
       {
          name=n; 
          ID= id; 
          count=c; 
       }
       Product()
       {

       }
     }; 
     class FV : public Product 
     {
       public: 
       FV()
       {

       }
       FV (int a)
       { 
         name="Apples"; 
         ID: "APP01"; 
       }
       void UpdateStock() 
       {
         count=count-1; 
       }

  };
```

Comment: You've got the right idea. If you make a class for everything, the program will just sprawl and become unmaintainable. Odds are a good you can implement the all with one class and a few extra member variables. If you have to use inheritance to satisfy an assignment requirement, Only you can decide the level at which you should stop. I'd stop at dairy and the different ID would be a member variable. Maybe I'd have support function like `make_egg` that returns a `Dairy` with the correct settings for an egg.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I fear that your question might be closed as too broad for this site as it does not contain a concrete programming question. It is always good to include some code and describe the problems you have in some detail.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define a `Product` class with id, name and count variables and inherit the four categories as child classes. Depending on your database design, your query to show items of same category can be different, but the idea is to find objects of the same type and use them as a data source for your ui.